# Remove/Correct Identity Verification from a signer from DocuSign SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I create an envelope and I want to implement the Correct functionality same as the DocuSign portal from API.

On creation I setup the authentication type to a signer and working perfectly.

```
Signer signer = new Signer
{
   Email = email,
   Name = name,
   RecipientId = recipientId
};

//On Create
RecipientSMSAuthentication smsAuth = new RecipientSMSAuthentication();
smsAuth.SenderProvidedNumbers = new List<string>();


foreach (var telephone in telephoneNumbers)
{
    smsAuth.SenderProvidedNumbers.Add(telephone);
}

signer.IdCheckConfigurationName = "SMS Auth $";
signer.SmsAuthentication = smsAuth;
```

When I try to correct this signer and remove or change (etc phone) this authentication type is not working

```
//On Update
signer.IdCheckConfigurationName = "";
signer.SmsAuthentication = null;
```

I use the UpdateAsync api call

```
Recipients Recipients = new Recipients();
List<Signer> Signers = new List<Signer>();
Signers.Add(signer);

Recipients.Signers = Signers;



await envelopesApi.UpdateAsync(accountId, envelopeId, new Envelope() { Recipients = Recipients }, new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions() { resendEnvelope = "true" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.
First, you're using the old method for SMS verification in this code. A new method which is going to give you more flexibility was introduced recently. It looks like this:

```
        RecipientIdentityVerification workflow = new RecipientIdentityVerification()
        {
            WorkflowId = workflowId,
            InputOptions = new List<RecipientIdentityInputOption> {
                new RecipientIdentityInputOption
                {
                    Name = "phone_number_list",
                    ValueType = "PhoneNumberList",
                    PhoneNumberList = new List<RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber>
                    {
                        new RecipientIdentityPhoneNumber
                        {
                            Number = phoneNumber,
                            CountryCode = countryAreaCode,
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Signer signer1 = new Signer()
        {
            Name = signerName,
            Email = signerEmail,
            RoutingOrder = "1",
            Status = "Created",
            DeliveryMethod = "Email",
            RecipientId = "1", //represents your {RECIPIENT_ID},
            Tabs = signer1Tabs,
            IdentityVerification = workflow,
        };
```

**Note** that your account may not have the new auth method enabled, you can either create a new developer account or contact support to enable it for you,.

Second, updating recipients of an existing envelopes has some limits. It can only be done if the envelope is in a "Draft" status ("created") and not after it was sent ("sent"). You may need to use the **Correct** action in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !
1) I can't find the Correct api call that you mention (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/upgrading-v21/)
2) The workfow id indicates if the phone or sms authentication will occur ? If so where can i find them in my portal ?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createcorrect/

Comment: This is both SMS/Phone call. The end-user gets to decide, their phone number is set ahead of time, but they choose if they want an SMS message or a phone call..

Comment: I contacted to the docusign support to enable the new auth for my dev account. I will come back to this post when i tested. I understand that the update api call can't remove the identity verification if exist. Thanks again !!!

Comment: If you use the new process you can update recipients without the need to use "Correct"

Comment: It's working , thanks again !!